# Database design of Railway reservation system

Tags: database-design

I am designing Railway reservation system.
I am having below tables.

```
StationTable(Contails all the stations to which i can provide the railway service.)
<StationID>->PrimaryKey
<StationName>

TrainTable
<TrainNumber>-> PrimaryKey
<TrainName>
<SourceStationID>->FK StationTable(<StationID>)
<DestinationStationID>->FK StationTable(<StationID>)
```

Passenger is identified by TicketID

```
   PassengerTable
    <TicketID>->Primary key
    <PassengerID>
    <PassengerName>
    <Age>
    <Sex>
    <Status>
```

As one passenger can book ticket for many trains. Their is many to many relation between TicketID and TrainID.

PassengerTrainTable
-> FK  PassengerTable()
-> FK TrainTable()

I am unable to relate to No of seats in a train and the status.
How can i relate those in relation with current table or how can i go with new tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many-to-many relationships are solved with the help of an extra table. In this case the ticket sale table is natural to your domain. See[image: the sample here]